# Why does a C3889 Error occur in xutility when I try to build/generate a C++ solution?

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors

I'm still new to C++, and I have to create an online store by defining a few classes. But the thing is, even after having gotten rid of all the errors in my files, Visual Studio shows me an error in an xutility file :
Error C3889 call to a class object « std::equal_to » : corresponding call operator not found.
I don't really know what this file is, but after a few researches I simply found out that there might be an error if one of my functions/classes has the same name as one from this file. Also, here is the part of the code where the error occurs ( last for loop, on _Pred ) :

> template <class _InIt1, class _InIt2, class _Pr>
> _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 bool equal(const _InIt1 _First1, const _InIt1 _Last1, const _InIt2 _First2, _Pr _Pred) {
> compare [_First1, _Last1) to [_First2, ...)
> _Adl_verify_range(_First1, _Last1);
> auto _UFirst1      = _Get_unwrapped(_First1);
> const auto _ULast1 = _Get_unwrapped(_Last1);
> auto _UFirst2      = _Get_unwrapped_n(_First2, _Idl_distance<_InIt1>(_UFirst1, _ULast1));
> if constexpr (_Equal_memcmp_is_safe<decltype(_UFirst1), decltype(_UFirst2), _Pr>) {
> #if _HAS_CXX20
> if (!_STD is_constant_evaluated())
> #endif // _HAS_CXX20
> {
> return _Memcmp_ranges(_UFirst1, _ULast1, _UFirst2) == 0;
> }
> }
>
> for (; _UFirst1 != _ULast1; ++_UFirst1, (void) ++_UFirst2) {
> if (!_Pred(*_UFirst1, *_UFirst2)) {
> return false;
> }
> }
>
> return true;
> }

I can't provide my code, for there are several files, but they're available here if it's necessary :
https://github.com/DZburst/TP2_Online_Store

Any help would truly be appreciated,
Thanks by advance

Comment: You might have to try commenting out portions of your code to narrow down what is triggering this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Client`:

```
std::ostream& client::operator<<(std::ostream& os, Client& client)
```

should have been

```
std::ostream& client::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Client& client)
//                                                 ^^^^^
```

and for that to work, the member function `client::Client::panier()` should be `const` qualified and preferably not return a *copy* of the `vector`, but a `const&` to the contained `vector`. Since you also need a non-`const` version in `Magasin` I suggest making the function overloaded. In both cases, return by reference:

```
std::vector<produit::Produit>& client::Client::panier()
//                           ^
std::vector<produit::Produit> const& client::Client::panier() const
//                            ^^^^^^                          ^^^^^
```

and

```
bool client::Client::operator==(Client& client)
```

should have been

```
bool client::Client::operator==(const Client& client) const
//                              ^^^^^                 ^^^^^
```

(or a non-member function taking two `Client`s by `const&`)

You should also `#include <vector>` in `Client.h`

---

`Produit`

```
bool produit::Produit::operator == (Produit& produit)
bool produit::Produit::operator != (Produit& produit)
```

should have been

```
bool produit::Produit::operator == (const Produit& produit) const
bool produit::Produit::operator != (const Produit& produit) const
//                                  ^^^^^                   ^^^^^
```

(or non-members taking two `Produit`s by `const&`)

---

With those fixed, it all compiles fine.